# error jquery elements DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, element

```
  var foto = 'htp://midomain.com/folder/pic.jpg';
  var img = new Image();
  $(img).attr({'src': foto, 'width':'100', 'height': '100'})
        .load(function(){
          $(this).hide();                                   
          $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    })
    .click(function(){
      var ancho = 0;
      var img2 = new Image();
      $(img2)
       .attr('src', $(this).attr('src'))
       .load(function(){
            $(this).hide();                                 
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            ancho = $(this).width();
            $(img2).attr({'width': $(this).width(), 'height': $(this).height()});
       });

$('body').appendTo(img);

console.log(ancho); //0
console.log($(img2).attr('width')); //undefined
//get width img2 :(
```

alguien puede obtener el valor de width and height

someone could help me please, I need to get the width of the element img2

edit:
I need the original width of the picture
thanks

Comment: Switch the order of `.attr` and `.load`. Bind the load event before you set the `src` attribute.

Comment: I need the original width of the picture

Comment: the console logs at the end that are undefined, they should be undefined. move them to inside the load event, otherwise they happen before the load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scoping issue, and there's a small issue with the order inwhich you are binding the load event and setting the attribute.

```
var foto = 'https://www.toontrack.com/getdbimage.asp?myproducts=7';
var img = new Image();
$(img).load(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).fadeIn('slow')
}).attr({
    'src': foto,
    'width': '100',
    'height': '100'
}).click(function() {
    var ancho = 0;
    var img2 = new Image();
    $(img2).load(function() {
        ancho = this.width;
        console.log(ancho);
    }).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
}).hide();
$('body').append(img);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9yw5H/

Also, you an shorten it to this with html5:

```
var foto = 'https://www.toontrack.com/getdbimage.asp?myproducts=7';
var img = new Image();
$(img).load(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).fadeIn('slow')
}).attr({
    'src': foto,
    'width': '100',
    'height': '100'
}).click(function() {
    var ancho = this.naturalWidth;
    console.log(ancho);
}).hide();
$('body').append(img);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9yw5H/1/

Comment: obtain the value of width after load

Comment: The image is already loaded, img2 contains the same img as img1, using the html5 version you can get that original width without creating img2.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var ancho = 0;
  var img2 = new Image();
  $(img2)
   .attr('src', $(this).attr('src'))
   .load(function(){
        $(this).hide();                                 
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        ancho = $(this).width();
        $(img2).attr({'width': $(this).width(), 'height': $(this).height()});
   });
```

Add this before this code block:

$(that) = $(this)

Then use $(that) like this:

$(img2)
    .attr('src', $(that).attr('src')
   ...etc

The problem is that when you are calling chained functions for $(img2) the scope of $(this) now referes to img2, not img1.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `$(this)` at that point in the code refers to `img1` because `img1` was clicked, not `img2`.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Once you are "inside" the img2 object, $(this) refers to that object and not the calling object.  This is a common scoping issue in JQuery.